# How to configure the views slideshow from the CMS?

Tags: 7, views

Currently I am configuring the views slideshow from the views edit. where I can set the interval time, slide show type and effect, control of the slideshow pause/stop/start etc.

My need is that I want to configure all these things from the CMS not from editing the view.

Is it possible? Is there any module which will do this? Or any other alternative for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check a very helpful module in Drupal [JCarousel](http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel). It has views integration and the settings which you want as well.

> This module allows developers and themers to make use of the jCarousel jQuery plugin. It includes a developer API that other modules can use, as well as Views integration in the 2.0 version so that you can turn any list of content or images into a carousel.